# Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModosNormales {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        int nx,ny,c,n;
        float lx;
        float ly;

        float fn;
        c=172;

        System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
        nx=teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
        ny=teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese lx:");
        lx=teclado.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Ingrese ly:");
        ly=teclado.nextFloat();
        fn=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny/ly),2)));

        System.out.print("Fn=");
        System.out.println(fn);

        for(n=0;n<10;n++) { 

            int nx1,ny1;
            float fn1;
            ArrayList<float> fn1= new ArrayList();


               System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
               nx1=teclado.nextInt();
               System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
               ny1=teclado.nextInt();
               fn1.add(n,c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny/ly),2)))); //en cada posición del array guardas un valor de fn1
               System.out.print("Fn=");
               System.out.println(fn1.get(n));


            }


            for (int i=0;i<fn1.size()-1;i++)
             {
                  if (fn1.get(i) = fn1.get(i+1))
             {
                aux++; //si el elemento actual es igual al siguiente, incrementamos la variable aux
              }
            }

               if(fn1[n]>=500)
        {System.out.println("Frecuencia mayor o igual a 500Hz"); break;





    }}}
```

`ArrayList<float> fn1= new ArrayList();`

¿por qué acá me dice? :

> Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType ?

Comment: Tienes que usar la clase `Float` no el primitivo: **`ArrayList<Float> fn1= new ArrayList();`**

Comment: Al ponerlo me salen como 5 errores mas en distintas lineas

Comment: Sí, tienes errores de declaración, por ejemplo declaras: `float fn1`;  y luego lo declaras como `ArrayList<float> fn1= new ArrayList();` ¿por qué?  o es un simple `float`  o es un ArrayList  de Floats, no las dos cosas a la vez... también quizá te dé error cuando agregas elementos al array. Corrige los errores de declaración, si da error ponlos en la pregunta indicando las líneas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código está plagado de errores.

Por ejemplo:

1. El método `main`:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] ar) {
   ```
2. Declaras `fn1` como `float` y al mismo tiempo como `ArrayList`. Además, lo haces dentro de un bucle.

   ```
    for(n=0;n<10;n++) { 
       int nx1,ny1;
       float fn1;
       ArrayList<float> fn1= new ArrayList();
   ```
3. A esta comparación le falta un signo de igualdad:

   ```
   if (fn1.get(i) = fn1.get(i+1))
   ```
4. La variable `aux++;` no está declarada.
5. Aquí `if(fn1[n]>=500)` debería usar `get`.

Como comentario, no acabo de ver la utilidad del último bucle `for` y el último `if` del código.

He corregido esos puntos y quizá otros, declarando las variables a su tiempo, etc. El código funciona (no da errores).

### Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModosNormales {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Float> fn1 = new ArrayList();
        int aux = 0; //No sé si debe valer 0, si no le pones el valor inicial que deba llevar
        int nx, ny, c, n;
        float lx;
        float ly;
        float fn;
        c = 172;

        System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
        nx = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
        ny = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese lx:");
        lx = teclado.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Ingrese ly:");
        ly = teclado.nextFloat();
        fn = c * (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx / lx), 2) + (float) (Math.pow((ny / ly), 2)));

        System.out.print("Fn=");
        System.out.println(fn);

        for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {

            int nx1, ny1;
//            float fn1;

            System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
            nx1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
            ny1 = teclado.nextInt();
            fn1.add(n, c * (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx / lx), 2) + (float) (Math.pow((ny / ly), 2)))); //en cada posición del array guardas un valor de fn1
            System.out.print("Fn=");
            System.out.println(fn1.get(n));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fn1.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (fn1.get(i) == fn1.get(i + 1)) {
                aux++; //si el elemento actual es igual al siguiente, incrementamos la variable aux
            }
        }

        if (fn1.get(n) >= 500) {
            System.out.println("Frecuencia mayor o igual a 500Hz");
        }

    }
}
```

### Una prueba

```
Ingrese valor de nx:10
Ingrese valor de ny:20
Ingrese lx:5
Ingrese ly:7
Fn=599.865
```